# Keyboard layout switch in fedora 31

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, keyboard-layout

Hi I've just installed **Fedora Generic 31 Generic (x86-64)** on my PC, I can't switch keyboard language with shortcuts and even can't find any setting for this. Is the any way to create shortcut for this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/edit the keyboard layout via [gnome settings](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-layouts.html.en):

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click Region & Language in the sidebar to open the panel.
4. Click the + button in the Input Sources section, select the language which is associated with the layout, then select a layout and press Add.

Alternatively you can change the layout from command line with [setxkbmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap)